# Prove that $\sum_n 1/(2n − 1)^4 = \pi^4/96$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Attempt: I found the Fourier series for $f(x) = \lvert x\rvert$

$a_0 = (1/\pi)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert r\rvert\,dr = \pi$

$a_n = (1/\pi)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert r\rvert\cos(nr)\,dr = (2/\pi n^2)((-1)^n – 1)$

$b_n = (1/\pi)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert r\rvert\sin(nr)\,dr = 0$

$f(x) = \pi/2 + \sum_n (2/\pi n^2)((-1)^n – 1)\cos(nx)$

The professor said to use this with Parseval's identity to do the proof. How do I do this?

Comment: This sum is $\dfrac{2^4-1}{2^4} \zeta(4)$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is even. Now you  basically directly apply the Parseval's identity to $f(x) = |x|$ and it should give you the result after one rearranging of the terms.

Comment: I did that and got $∑(1 - (-1)^n)/13n^4 = π^4/96$. How do I show that two infinite series are equal? Is there a theorem for this?

Comment: what are the possible values of $1-(-1)^n ?$. There are only two possible values, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.  Also, it seems like you made some calculation mistake. Number $13$ should not show up when you calculate the integral on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
& \text{Proof of } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n-1)^4} =\frac{\pi^2}{96} \\
& \text{Think of } f(x)=|x| \quad-\pi \leq x \leq \pi \\
& \therefore a_0=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x \mathop{dx}=\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \pi^2=\pi \\
& \therefore a_n=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi x \cos n x \mathop{dx} \\
& =\frac{2}{n \pi} \int_0^\pi x \mathop{d \sin nx} \\
& =\frac{-2}{n \pi} \int_0^\pi \sin n x \mathop{dx} \\
& =\frac{2}{n^2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \mathop{d \cos nx} \\
& =\frac{2}{n^2 \pi}\left[(-1)^n-1\right] \\
& \because f(x)\text{ is even function}\\
& \therefore b_n=0 \\
& \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) \mathop{dx} \\
& =2 \int_0^\pi x^2 \mathop{dx} \\
& =\frac{2}{3} \pi^3 \\
& \text{Thanks to Parseval Equation} \\
& \frac{a_0^2}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n^2+b_n^2\right)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) \mathop{dx} \\
& \because \text{If n is even, then } a_n=0 \\
& \therefore \text{Let }n=2k-1 ,\text{ we have:}\\
& \frac{\pi^2}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\{\left[\frac{-4}{(2 k-1)^2}\right]^2+0^2\right\}=\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \pi^3 \\
& \therefore \frac{\pi^2}{2}+16 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 k-1)^4}=\frac{2 \pi^2}{3} \\
& \therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 k-1)^4}=\frac{\pi^2}{96}
\end{aligned}